# Appending and substracting divs filled with data from one simple form to a form that contains all the divs grouped and ready to POST

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, forms

So this is the deal:

I have an order page and I use two forms.

The first form contains input data for ONE order item and when I press OK I will pass the form's input data to javascript through `onsubmit=send_item_data(this)` and at the end i will `return false;` in send_item_data function so it doesn't get posted.

In the second one I want to append/substract the former data in div groups (so I can add more or delete them easily) but I can't think (or find) of a solution that puts in group the data from the first form in one div and appends that child div to the second form.

In the end, by the push of a button, the second form will post all the divs' data and I will handle it with PHP backend code.

Code body:

```
<form action="" id="first_form" method="post" onsubmit="return send_item_data(this)"> 

    <div id="Select_list">
        <select blah blah>
            ---bunch of options---
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="extras">
                ---Some extras that you can choose by a checkbox input (I generate it via PHP)---
                example:
                <input name="checkbox[<?php echo $row['column_data_from_query']?>]" type="checkbox" value="checked">
    </div>

            --->Possibly two more input fields here<---

    <input type="button" value="clear" onclick="clear_form()">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>

<form action="" id="finalize_order_form" method="post"> 
   --->This is the second form<---
   --->In here I want to put the data from the first form so i can handle them by group<---

    if I click OK three times in the first form there should be three groups here that contain each form's data
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Finallize order"/>
</form>
```

I mainly use PHP Mysql and Javascript (including AJAX, not jQuery).

Comment: Are you trying to add additional order items?  What is not working?  Perhaps you might post your JS.  It is unwise to store the data only clientside.  I suggest you at least add a db table and ajax call to store the changes so they can 1. be retrieved later 2. allow you to see what users were thinking of ordering, even if they didn't.

Comment: At the backend all data is stored in the database (2 tables --> one for storing order id, time and waitor id and the other one contains the order items). I found an example that shows how to append div elements (through JS) but the main problem is: how do I put together the input data from the first order inside the appending div and THEN add it to the second form.

Comment: After that I will try giving users the ability to delete any div they want(from the 2nd form) and an edit function so when they click something like "<a onclick="edit_item(...)><edit> Edit </edit></a>" the item gets sent to the first form so they can edit it.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to have the order items listed in the second form like a pre-checkout shopping cart.  If you use divs for that, they will not be submitted with the POST data to the server - they will be display-only.  So you need to follow Robert's advice and save the 1st form's data to the DB each time an item is added/removed (in addition to his other reasons like not losing a customer's session info).  That way the DB will already be up-to-date when they click Confirm Order.  Or else you need to hook the Confirm Order button to a JS function that converts the divs back to JSON and posts that to the server to be stored in the DB.

As far as creating the display-only div from the 1st form's data, your send_item_data function needs to loop over all the form's inputs, get their values, and add them to the div however you want them to be displayed.  Then you can just insert the div into the second form.  Since you are passing "this" to the function, which is the form object itself, you can get the inputs via something like:

```
var inputs = this.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type == 'submit') continue; //ignore the Submit button
    var name = inputs[i].name, value = inputs[i].value;
    ---use the name and value of this input to construct a span or something to insert inside your div---
}
---now you can insert the div into the 2nd form---
```